# Which language extensions enable to write "class A (B c) => D c where ..." ? What is the meaning of this type class declaration?

Tags: haskell, ghc, typeclass, frp, type-families

I am trying to understand the following class declaration :

```
class (MonadHold t (PushM t), MonadSample t (PullM t), Functor (Event t), Functor (Behavior t)) => Reflex t where
  data Behavior t :: * -> *
```

which is in the [Reflex](https://github.com/ryantrinkle/reflex/blob/master/src/Reflex/Class.hs) FRP library.

1 ) What language extensions make it possible to write `Functor (Behavior t) => Reflex t` ? I guess it is a combination of Language extensions. I am guessing Type Families are involved, but what else ?

In other words, what language extension do I have to turn on such that a code containing `class A (B c) => D c where ...` compiles ?

2 ) What is the meaning of `class A (B c) => D c where ...` ?

3 ) Could you give a super simple example explaining why and when one wants to write `class A (B c) => D c where ...` ?

4 ) Where is it described what  `class A (B c) => D c where ...` means ? I guess there is an SPJ paper or talk describing it could you please point to it ?

Edit:

Further related info:

[Here](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.4/docs/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html) it is written:

> In Haskell 98 the context of a class declaration (which introduces
>   superclasses) must be simple; that is, each predicate must consist of
>   a class applied to type variables.

If I interpret the above citation correctly then in Haskell98 only `class A b=>C b where` shaped class declarations are allowed, which means that `class A(B c) => D c` is not allowed. So the question is, if the latter is allowed, and the former is not, who and what defines the MEANING for the latter ? The latter is not correct Haskell 98 syntax so its meaning is also not described in any Haskell 98 book, then where it is the MEANING of the latter described/documented/specified?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, as you've correctly guessed, `Behaviour` is an [associated data type](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Type_families#Detailed_definition_of_data_families), so falls under the `TypeFamilies` extension.

The point of `class Functor (Behaviour t) => Reflex t where data Behaviour t :: * -> *` is to enforce the requirement that for any type `t` which is an instance of `Reflex`, whatever datatype you define as the associated data type `Behaviour t`, you must also make that type into an instance of `Functor`.

Here's a small example: suppose I this class definition:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, FlexibleContexts #-}

class Functor (F a) => Funky a where
    data F a :: * -> *
```

This allows writing something like

```
frobulate :: (Funky a) => F a Int -> F a Bool
frobulate = fmap (< 5)
```

since `frobulate` is free to assume from `Funky a` that `Functor (F a)`.

The following by itself is rejected by the type checker:

```
instance Funky Int where
    data F Int a = MkF a
```

because the associated datatype `F Int` is not an instance of `Functor`:

```
No instance for (Functor (F Int))
  arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration
In the instance declaration for `Funky Int'
```

which forces you to also add an instance definition like

```
instance Functor (F Int) where
    fmap f (MkF x) = MkF (f x)
```

Note that the latter `Functor` instance also requires `FlexibleInstances` to be turned on.

Comment: Many thanks, where is this defined "The point of class Functor (Behaviour t) => Reflex t where data Behaviour t :: * -> * is to enforce the requirement that for any type t which is an instance of Reflex, whatever datatype you define as the associated data type Behaviour t, you must also make that type into an instance of Functor." ? How do you know this ? Which SPJ paper describes this ?

Comment: More specifically , where is the meaning of the syntax `Functor (F a) => Funky a` defined ? Is it in the type families papers of SPJ ?

Comment: @jhegedus That's just ordinary type class constraint syntax. Its meaning doesn't really change when type families are involved (type families just adds more kinds of things you can mention in constraints). `class Functor (F a) => Funky a` just means that for all instances declared for the `Funky` class there must be a `Functor` instance for `F a` (for the same `a`). This is no different from how `class Eq a => Ord a` means that for all instances of `Ord` there must be an instance of `Eq`.

Comment: @Ben The difference I mean is the difference between `Functor (F a) => Funky a` and `F a => Funky a`, the latter is classical, ordinary type class construct, the former, AFAIK is not. What do you think ? Can you write `class A( B c) => D c where ...` in Haskell 98 without turning on some language extensions ? I think not but I am not sure.

Comment: @Ben how do YOU know the following : "class Functor (F a) => Funky a just means that for all instances declared for the Funky class there must be a Functor instance for F a (for the same a)"? Where is this rule coming from ? I think this rule is not described in textbooks on Haskell98. So where is it described ? In other words, how do YOU know what "class Functor (F a) => Funky a" MEANS ? Have you read about this somewhere ? If yes, where ?

Comment: @jhegedus I can't remember off the top of my head. You *can* definitely write things like `class Eq a => Eq (Maybe a)` though. There's not really any new concepts involved in saying `class Eq (Maybe a) => Eq a` instead, whether or not it's Haskell 98.

Comment: @jhegedus The rule is just that in a class declaration the stuff before the `=>` is specifying constraints that must hold for every instance of the class that is declared. All I need to know is how to read a constraint (every Haskell text or tutorial that covers type classes at all will go over the basics of this), and that specifically for class declarations it's a constraint that must be satisfied for every instance. That's true whether the constraint is one allowed by Haskell 98 or a more advanced one.

Comment: @jhegedus did you miss the `FlexibleContexts` bit in my sample code by chance?

Comment: No, that is alright. I can see that. But that alone does not say where it is the meaning of the class declaration defined, it is not in any Haskell98 textbooks AFAIK.

Comment: @Cactus It's my 4th question for which I search the answer, all the 1-3 parts are answered, for which I am very thankful.

Comment: @jhegedus I'm not sure that you'll find much more of the meaning of *specifically* the type class constraints that you can write with FlexibleContexts; even the GHC documentation for the FlexibleContexts extension (which you quote and link to) doesn't say much about what the constraints mean, just about the now-allowed form of the constraints. The reason is that the constraints still mean exactly the same thing as they always did ("there must be an instance matching this constraint when you use the thing I'm declaring"), you can just use more flexible rules for defining the constraints.

Comment: @Ben, basically when you say `A t => B t` then that means that `t` must be of type `A` if  `t` is of type `B` right ? This is a predicate, so generalizing this rule would give : writing `A b => B t` implies that `b` must be of type `A` if `t` is of type `B`, right ?  This rule generalization was confusing me and I was just looking for some specification where  this generalization is described. Perhaps this is the only meaningful generalization of the basic Haskell 98 rule and that is the reason why it is not specified anywhere explicitly.

Comment: @jhegedus: does http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/Papers/type-class-design-space/ contain an answer to what you think your question is?

Answer (score 3):

For part 4: the Haskell Report [says](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-770004.3.2):

> Assume that the type variables in the instance type `(T u1 … uk)` satisfy the constraints in the instance context `cx′`. Under this assumption, the following two conditions must also be satisfied:
>
> 1. The constraints expressed by the superclass context `cx[(T u1 … uk)/u]` of `C` must be satisfied. In other words, `T` must be an instance of each of `C`'s superclasses and the contexts of all superclass instances must be implied by `cx′`.
> 2. Any constraints on the type variables in the instance type that are required for the class method declarations in `d` to be well-typed must also be satisfied.

None of this discussion assumes that superclass contexts are of the simplified form demanded elsewhere in the report; and therefore can (and does) serve as the meaning of more complicated superclass contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my understanding of the answers. It took me a while to understand it, so I write it down, perhaps it helps for others.

The traditional type class declaration (Haskell 98) `class (Eq a) => MyClass a where` **says** that if `a` is an instance of `MyClass` then `a` has to be an instance of `Eq`, the left side `Eq a` ( meaning that `a` is instance of `Eq`) is a predicate that has to be true if the right side is true `MyClass a` (meaning that `a` is instance of `MyClass`).

So in other words a class declaration is like `class ($Predicate) => MyClass classInstance`, where `$Predicate` can be for example `Eq a` which means that `a` is an instance of `Eq`.

But if one enables the `FlexibleContexts` language extension then the predicate can be something more complex than just `ATypeClass typeParameter`.

It can be `ATypeClass SomeComplexType` which means - by **generalizing** the rule for Haskell 98 that `SomeComplexType` is an instance of `ATypeClass`.

This generalization process is described implicitly in the Haskell Report (as explained in Daniel's answer).

The following three short programs demonstrate this generalization rule. The first one compiles the second one not and the third one compiles again.

The second one fails to compile because `Smells` is not `StringLike`, as required in `IntLike`'s class declaration. However if we remove that constraint (in the third program) then the program compiles again.

Here is a toy example which compiles:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}


class StringLike a where
 getString :: a->String

class (StringLike Smells) =>IntLike a where
 getInt :: a-> Int

instance IntLike Colors where
  getInt x = 0

instance StringLike Colors where
 getString x = "Hello"

instance StringLike Smells where
 getString x = "Bad"

data Colors = Blue | Red
data Smells = Rose | Trash
```

The following fails however:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}


class StringLike a where
 getString :: a->String

class (StringLike Smells) =>IntLike a where
 getInt :: a-> Int

instance IntLike Colors where
  getInt x = 0

instance StringLike Colors where
 getString x = "Hello"


data Colors = Blue | Red
data Smells = Rose | Trash
```

with the  error message:

```
test.hs:10:10:
    No instance for (StringLike Smells)
      arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration
    In the instance declaration for `IntLike Colors'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

However, the following compiles again just fine :

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}


class StringLike a where
 getString :: a->String

class (StringLike Smells) =>IntLike a where
 getInt :: a-> Int


instance StringLike Colors where
 getString x = "Hello"


data Colors = Blue | Red
data Smells = Rose | Trash
```